# Reliable detection of QProcess finishing

Tags: qt, qprocess

I have a Windows Qt application that uses `QProcess` to run an external program which may or may not need input. The input will *always* be `y` followed by <kbd>ENTER</kbd> if needed. And, if `y` is entered, the program exits immediately.

So the actions I take in the code are:

```
QProcess process;
QString cmd = QString("myprog.exe %1").arg(myParam);

process.start(cmd);
if (! process.waitForStarted(10000))
{
    logError("Timed out starting preparation!");
    return;
}
process.write("y\n");
if (! process.waitForFinished(5000))
{
    process.kill();
    process.waitForFinished(5000);
    logError("Timed out finishing preparation!");
    return;
}
```

Now I will often see that final error message *despite* the fact that the process appears to have worked correctly (entering `y` can be detected after the event so I know it's happening). This is intermittent.

Investigations have led me to the Qt `QProcess` doco, which has this gem:

> ***`bool QProcess::waitForFinished(int msecs = 30000)`***
>
> Blocks until the process has finished and the `finished()` signal has been emitted, or until `msecs` milliseconds have passed.
>
> Returns true if the process finished; otherwise returns `false` (if the operation timed out, if an error occurred, or if this `QProcess` is already finished).

I *suspect* it may be that last sentence which is biting me. Since the process exits as soon as you enter `y`, I think it's no longer there when I get to the point of first calling `WaitForFinished()`. So that function will return false and I'll assume it didn't work properly.

So I have two questions based on that. First, is my understanding correct? Is there a chance that the process will have exited before checking and will that result in a false return value.

Second, if that *is* the case, how would you tell the difference between a process that has exited before you check, and one that hasn't exited before your time-out kicks in?

Comment: As seen in the [source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qprocess.cpp.html#_ZN8QProcess15waitForFinishedEi), it checks if the process state is `QProcess::NotRunning` and returns false if so. You could do this check yourself before calling `QProcess::waitForFinished`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you think that the process is already closed when you call `waitForFinished()`, you should check if the process is running.

```
process.write("y\n");
process.waitForFinished(5000)
if(process.state() != QProcess::NotRunning)
{ 
  ..
}
```